# Proving that metric spaces are normal

Tags: general-topology

I am studying Abraham and Jerrlod's *Foundations of Mechanics*. In proposition 1.1.9, they prove that any metric space $M$ is normal by considering any two disjoint closed subsets $A$ and $B$ of $M$, and then claiming that the sets
\begin{align}
U&:=\{u\in M:d(u, A)<d(u, B)\}\\
V&:=\{v\in M:d(v, A)>d(v, B)\}\\
\end{align}
are open, disjoint and satisfy $A\subset U$ and $B\subset V$.

It's only openness that I am having trouble to show (rest are easy). It is here that the closedness of $A$ and $B$ must be used (since the rest two don't use it). But I've not been able to find, for a general $u\in U$, an $\varepsilon>0$ such that $D_\varepsilon(u)\subset U$.

Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $u \in U$ and $0 <r <\frac  {d(u,B)-d(u,A)} 3$. Let us show that $d(v,u)<r$ implies $v \in U$. There exists $a \in A$ such that $d(u,a) <d(u,A) +r$. Now $d(v,A)\leq d(v,a) <d(v,u)+d(u,a)<2r+d(u,A) <d(u,B)-d(v,u) <d(v,B)$. This proves that $U$ is open.

An alternative argument is to prove (using triangle inequality) that $d(u,B)-d(u,A)$ is a continuous function from which we see that $U$ is the inverse image of  an open set under a continuous function.

Comment: This is amusing that the former proof doesn't use the closedness of $A$ and $B$ at all!

Comment: Can we then say that in a metric space, **any two subsets** $A$ and $B$ have disjoint neighborhoods?

Comment: @Atom Openness of $U$ and $V$ holds for any subsets $A$ and $B$.

Comment: @Atom My answer is only for openness. It is obviously not true that any two sets have disjoint neighborhoods.

Comment: But $U\cap V = \emptyset$, $A\subset U$ and $B\subset V$ also hold irrespective of closedness of $A$ or $B$, right?

Comment: @Atom You said 'rest is easy' once openness is proved. The fact that $A$ and $B$ are disojoint closed sets is needed  in the 'rest', not in proving that $U$ and $V$ are open.

Comment: Yes, I realised that I have to use the disjointness and closedness in proving $A\subset U$ and $B\subset V$. Thanks!

Comment: YOu can show any separate d$A$ and $B$ have disjoint neighbourhoods so that $\overline{A}\cap B = \emptyset = \overline{B} \cap A$.

Answer (score 1):

The metric  $d $ is continuous wrt the metric topology (the metric topology is the coarsest such topology).   Thus $\hat d:X\to\mathbb R_{\ge0} $ by $\hat d (x)=d (x,A)-d (x,B) $ is continuous.   But $V=\hat d^{-1}((0,\infty) $ is then open.   Similarly for  $U $.

If $A $ and  $B $ are not closed,  the argument breaks down:  we don't get $A\subset U $ and $B\subset V $.  Them being closed guarantees a positive distance between them.